# I created filter and it removed all mail from inbox

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I wanted to create a filter for a particular address but instead it removed all mail from my inbox. Then I deleted the filter without finding out what it did. Can anyone help me to restore the messages that6 were in my inbox?

Comment: Now how to I get all those email back to my inbox :-)

Comment: The current answer already explains that. If that was not clear please post a comment directly to the answer asking for a clarifiation.

Answer (score 1):

If your messages were **archived** or **deleted** they will no longer show in the Inbox.

### Where did they go?

1. **If Archived**
   They can be found in the **All Mail** folder: [mail.google.com/#all](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all)
2. **If Deleted**
   They can be found in the **Trash** folder:  [mail.google.com/#trash](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#trash)

### How to Return them?

In both cases, select any affected messages and then click the **Move to Inbox** button
[image]

Comment: I have done this many a time and I still have to go to all mail to transfert some new mail to inbox

Comment: 1. Every single message in your Gmail account is always in your "All Mail" folder.  That includes Inbox, Sent Items etc.  If you have new messages coming in that are not in your INBOX, then they will be in your SPAM folder.  2. If they are arriving and are neither in your SPAM folder, nor in your INBOX, then you have a rule that is filtering the mail.  If you are describing 2 and not confused about 1, then you need to really take a good look in https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/filters for a rule trhat is moving the messages.  Good luck.